# Printing an SVG from HTML in landscape mode

Tags: html, css, svg

Okay so my setup is a window object created on the fly.

I'm writing to it with `window.document.write()` and building out this:

```
<style>
    @page{
        size: landscape;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;}
    svg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        overflow: visible;
        transform: scale(1, 1.3737);}
</style>
```

and then I clone the SVG from the page it's on and `document.write(svgClone.innerHTML)`.

I end up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/je0ssLm2/1/

Please excuse the mess but that contains the entire code for the SVG and displays how it renders. The reason I'm scaling by 1.3737 on the Y axis is because the image is 1280 x 720 but 1280 x 989 is close to an aspect ratio of 1:3 which is approximately the AR of US letter.

Anyway, as you can see the display is not very attractive, and when it prints for some reason the margins are very large and the image is quite small and not quite centered in the screen. Is there some crucial CSS I am missing? This is driving me nuts, I've seen a few other answers about this and tried various but I just can't get it to print correctly.

I'm not as worried about size as I am positioning. I can monkey with the scaling to get the size right but if I make the image bigger then I'll cut off axis labels or the title because the graph doesn't center on the page. I also ALWAYS get an extra blank page, which isn't the end of the world but definitely isn't desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify attributes on the `<svg>` element for a clean solution.

SVG has two attributes that let you describe scale-to-fit operations declaratively without computing transforms yourself: [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) and [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

Instead of the attributes you have

```
<svg width="1280" height="720">
```

you can write

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 720" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

If you cannot get at the source text, you can simply wrap the `<svg>` in a second one:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1280 720" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <svg width="1280" height="720">...</svg>
</svg>,
```

and, as long as you define sensible sizes, should work in all media, including the page the SVG originally comes from.

The area defined by the viewBox in SVG userspace coordinates will then be fitted into the size of the `<svg>` element itself - since you have it defined in CSS with `width:100%;height:100%;`, it is fitted into the containing element.

`preserveAspectRatio="none"` does the uneven scaling for you. This didn't work before because as a default, the aspect ratio was preserved (and only after being scaled-down-to-fit, the CSS transform cut in).

Comment: unfortunately this solution will not work for me because I don't personally generate the SVG, it is a graph generated by google charts so I can't remove the height and width properties.

Comment: Edited to reflect that.

Comment: brilliant! had no idea this was possible